# How to retrieve number of tags from xml document using findall from elementTree in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree, findall

I have reading some of the responses on stack and trying to work out this problem for a while.

I want to be able to output:

- Number of elements with the same tag (such as foo, bar and type)
- Numbers inside the attributes(such as foobar)

Sample Expected output(or any variation of that:

```
foo, 1
bar, 2
type, 8

foobar, 10
foobar, 20
```

I am trying to do it without using the `root` and `child` node method.

XML Document

```
<first>
   <foo>
      <bar>
        <type foobar="1"/>
        <type foobar="2"/>
        <type foobar="3"/>
        <type foobar="4"/>
      </bar>
      <bar>
        <type foobar="1"/>
        <type foobar="2"/>
        <type foobar="3"/>
        <type foobar="4"/>
      </bar>
   </foo>
</first>
```

Python Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fname = 'Library4.xml' # handle
stuff   = ET.parse(fname)

for atype in stuff.findall('type'):
    print(atype.get('foobar'))

all     = stuff.findall('bar')
print('bar', all)

all     = stuff.findall('foo')
print('foo', all)
```

Output that I am getting:

```
bar []
foo [<Element 'foo' at 0x000001E3C71F8B38>]
```

Happy to clarify further. Appreciate any help to point out my errors and mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use something like below code and calculate the appearance's, follow the below code as an example.

```
  from xml.dom import minidom
  fname = 'library4.xml'
  xmldoc = minidom.parse('library4.xml') 
  print("type " + str(len(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('type'))))
  print("foo " + str(len(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('foo'))))
  print("bar " + str(len(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('bar'))))
```

and the output for this is as below:

```
  type 8
  foo 1
  bar 2
```

Comment: I saw some stack posts that use 'minidom'. But I am trying to do that directly using the parse and findall. online resources seem to suggest that it is possible, but I figure out how.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html, under 20.5.3. Reference
20.5.3.1. Functions